# Formats for data consisting of value and pixel position in 3D

Tags: format, sparse-matrix

I'm building a device that translates a camera along 3 perpendicural axes. For the purpose of this question the camera cannot rotate, only translate. The purpose of the device is to take images at different positions such that all that data would later be transform in a 3D "image" of what the camera registered.

I figured that after processing all the individual frames, knowing the position at which they were taken, I should get a collection of data points that consist of a number of RBG vectors to which a position is assigned.

Is there a standard data format for this? I tried googling but, not being familiar with the terminology, I get stuff about 3D printing and CAD stuff.

The closest data structute that i can think of is something along the lines of sparse matrices, where, if i understand them properly, the information is recorded as a collection of values and indeces. On my case, instead of indices i would have float since positions are given by the precition of my motors.